# Spain2 node: instance rebooting forever

Tags: fiware, filab

i'm working on the Spain2 node. I'm trying to reboot an instance, but the instance keeps in the "rebooting" state forever. I have tried to shut off the instance, it doesn't work. After shutting off, the instance keeps in the "rebooting" state.

What can I do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I know what's happening: there is a hardware problem in the Spain2 node. That's the reason why the instance is having problems.

Answer (score 0):

the service was recovered again in Spain2 node. Try it again and if you have any problem send us a ticket through the mail list fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org